# how to read from a Persian pdf file in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want read persian pdf

my code is here

```
 try
        {
            string strText = string.Empty;
            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/attached/MAWB/711/114d1.pdf");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new Uri(path));

            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;

            }
            reader.Close();

            return Ok(strText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            while (ex.InnerException != null)
                ex = ex.InnerException;
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
```

and output like here

> F
>   Giti Resan Kala
>   Vtf 
>   rrtrD,, 
>   "Af 
>   JiJ 9 J.os 
>   s.f,1rir 
>   OtOyU.:suN3
>   \ Yltl \ /Yl 
>   ,tlJ q oS)9 
>   6'l- 
>   jU 
>   \ vt-Af 
>   . yy6 
>   \ f 
>   :(:.*) a*U1U o.,t-o.I, 
>   :a;l olLo*!
>   \44.... r(pt'1lJ)6.19 
>   \ftAyrA 
>   :lUlua*i 
>   \ \f 
>   :aJ.fj ct.u.,.
>   fq, fA o.:to f 
>   9 
>   l {i 
>   ..,ai.,"r./,$.,,{
>   * 
>   YAf Af 
>   :rij*:.o o;h*i
>   ..
>   1,:j
>   ,A 1... f.A. Y
>   tA 1... YYf f.
>   t 41... f r.1.
>   HADI BARGHAMADI
>   ,Al...t1rfA VA]IHEI,I RAMESHK
>   rA 1... YYY r I
>   SEVDA HOBEVATAN
>   DADEHVARZI
>   WIRELESS COMBO
>   tA 1...YY1.1
>   MR. BAIIRAM
>   FARAJI BAZARGANI
>   ,A 1... rf.rl
>   , A\,,,Y f,?f
>   tAl...Yf.tf
>   tAl... Yr.rv
>   2^..,Y?,rA
>   ,A 1...Yf, Y.
>   tAl... rf. YI
>   tAl...Yf . 
>   YY
>   tA't...rf.vf
>   ,A 1... rf. va
>   ,Al...Yf . 
>   Vt
>   \,ta\
>   qlt
>   6rl I 
>   qxp

pdf exist in below url

http://bre-shop.com/images/114d1.pdf

Comment: What is your `Encoding.Default`? I'm guessing it is _not_ the encoding that is used in your pdf...

Comment: Im test again whit Encoding.UTF8 but not working

Comment: The question is, what is the encoding of your pdf? Now wonder that converting from UTF-8 to UTF-8 doesn't work, because that pdf doesn't look a lot like UTF-8.

Comment: This looks like an OCR document with garbage as text. It was probably decoded with an OCR for western languages.

Comment: This document is Persian language

Comment: The software that did the OCR did not properly recognize the Persian text, so it contains garbage text. The fact you recognize Persian text on the page does not mean that inside the document it knows it is Persian.

Comment: Hadi, just like Paulo and iPDFdev say, the textual information in your PDF is garbage, OCR gone haywire. You should either drop the contained textual information and OCR again, or type in the information manually. @PauloSoares you might consider making your comment an answer.

Comment: Thanks from all. I think so i type the information

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an OCR document with garbage as text. It was probably decoded with an OCR for western languages, in other words, the OCR didn't know about Persian.